# Why do some vaccines cause flu-like symptoms? Why does this seem to be more severe in mRNA vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system

Flu like symptoms are noted as possible reactions on nearly every vaccine I've had since adolescence, but I've never actually seen these symptoms in myself or anyone, until now? I don't doubt that they happen, but the fact that I've never seen them to me says that they're not very common?
However, with the recent COVID19 vaccines, nearly everyone taking an mRNA (or AstraZeneca) vaccine reports having about 24 hours of a fever at the very least.

- Are reactions more common in mRNA vaccines?
- Is there something different about mRNA vaccines that makes the reactions more common/severe?
- Is fixing these reactions feasible? Would this affect effectiveness?

Comment: Are you sure they actually cause more symptoms? There has never been a vaccine in my lifetime that has had as much media scrutiny and discussion about side effects. Social media is flooded with talk about the vaccines and their side effects when that's never been the case before for any vaccine. I think the nocebo effect is extraordinarily strong with this one.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I'm pretty sure they do.  "Flu-like symptoms" are simply a sign of immune-system activation, and activating the immune system is the whole point of vaccination.

Comment: @Mark I get that but the question is whether mRNA vaccines cause **more** symptoms than other vaccines, and I'm not so sure they do, particularly if we're including all vaccines.

Comment: In the bullet points at the bottom, I do ask if there are more reactions in mRNA vaccines. If there is evidence that shows there aren't more reactions than that would be an easy answer, I'd have no choice but to select that answer ;)

(also the question asks why "Why does this **seem** to be more severe in mRNA vaccines?")